# How to call service outside istio mesh

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I have a multi-cluster on different netwroks setup working 100%.

My cluster-1 is exposing an east/west gateway, to be able to cluster-2 intercomunicate with it.

My cluster-2 has also deployments outside the mesh (without istio proxy injected).

How can I request to a service in cluster-1 from a deployment/pod (without proxy injected) in cluster-2? Can I use the east/west gateway? What are my options here? Can someone provide examples?

Comment: If the client workload is outside of the mesh your option is to configure your ingress gateway (in cluster1) and call the target service. My guess is you have a PASSTHROUGH configuring in your EW gateway; you could configure another port to listen on and use that as an ingress point for non-mesh services.